# AppStore BUG: CFBundleIconName in WatchKitApp is missing - but when added the **key** itself is invalid?

Tags: ios, app-store, plist, watchkit

We seem to be getting a self-contradictory set of error messages for our iOS App being submitted to the App Store.

The error begins simple enough and says we are missing a plist value. Here's the error below we receive by email from Apple after uploading our app to the store.

> Missing Info.plist value - **A value** for the Info.plist key
>   'CFBundleIconName' **is missing** in the bundle
>   'com.athla.velocity.ultimate.watchkitapp'. Apps built with iOS 11 or
>   later SDK must supply app icons in an asset catalog and must also
>   provide a value for this Info.plist key. For more information see
>   http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7.

But, if we add this key with its value to the plist file, we get an error saying that the **key itself** is invalid and we cannot even upload the app to the store. Here is the error:

> ERROR ITMS-90363: "Invalid Info.plist key. **The key** 'CFBundleIconName'
>   in bundle Velocity Ultimate.app/Watch/Velocity WatchKit App.app is
>   **invalid**."

These errors are self-contradictory.

How do we solve this so we can upload our app to the store - but not get blocked for having this key in the plist file?

Comment: were you able to solve this? we are facing same issue

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the same set of issues.

In Finder, I opened the WatchKit App Info.plist file in a text editor.  I removed the following lines:

```
<key>CFBundleIconName</key> 
<string>AppIcon</string>
```

After that, the error went away and I was able to upload to App Store Connect.

Hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by doubleclick Info.plist -> Visual Assets -> AppIcons. Previously it was "Source: none", so I have selected "Source: AppIcon". I am using Visual Studio making watch app with Xamarin. After that Info.plist was changed from:

```
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Resources/Images.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset</string>
```

to

```
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `CFBundleIconName` from Info.plist, as suggested by @sulli233, and the error is still there, it might mean that you need to supply an app icon.

In Xcode, click on `Assets.xcassets` of the project that is failing to build, and supply the necessary images.

In this case, the error message is wrong - it says that the `CFBundleIconName` is missing, but what is really missing are the images themselves.